# Envoy filter for outbound https traffic

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to intercept all outbound http/s traffic from a pod and add a custom header to the request. After reading some documentation I came to the understanding that an envoy filter on SIDECAR_OUTBOUND with some custom lua code would do the trick. So this is the configuration that I did:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: outbound-filter
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              subFilter:
                name: envoy.router
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                  request_handle:logWarn("Hello World")
                  request_handle:headers():add("origin", os.getenv("ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME"))
              end
```

And it works perfectly fine for http requests. However, it seems that the filter does not run at all when the request is over https and I don't understand what is the reason for that.
Is there any way to apply the filter for https requests as well?

Answer (score 0):

if envoy doesn't know how to decrypt the traffic, it won't be able to add header to the request

Comment: reason why http works because envoy sidecars by default using ISTIO_MTLS to encrypt and decrypt the traffic